# How to make “See all category” link button to display rest of the text with jquery 1.11 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue on the dropdown text.

**Below snippet using jquery 1.11.1**

```js
$(".more").toggle(function(){
    $(this).text("Less category").siblings(".complete").show();    
}, function(){
    $(this).text(" All category").siblings(".complete").hide();    
});
```

```css
.complete{
    display:none;
}

.more{
    background:black;
    color:red;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

li{
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>kategori 1</li>
    <li>kategori 2</li>
    <li class="complete">kategori 3</li>
    <li class="complete">kategori 4</li>
    <li class="complete">kategori 5</li>
    <li class="more">See all category</li>
</ul>
```

**Below snippet using jquery 1.8.3**

```js
$(".more").toggle(function(){
    $(this).text("Less category").siblings(".complete").show();    
}, function(){
    $(this).text(" All category").siblings(".complete").hide();    
});
```

```css
.complete{
    display:none;
}

.more{
    background:black;
    color:red;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

li{
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>kategori 1</li>
    <li>kategori 2</li>
    <li class="complete">kategori 3</li>
    <li class="complete">kategori 4</li>
    <li class="complete">kategori 5</li>
    <li class="more">See all category</li>
</ul>
```

Problem is, "See all category" text will disappear if I use jquery 1.9.1 and above. 
If I use jquery 1.8.3 and lower "See all category will appear and work just fine.

Can anyone help, thanks anyway :)

Comment: This variant of the `toggle` function was removed in jQuery 1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the click handler as this variant of [toggle is removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) in jQuery 1.9

```js
$(".more").click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text == 'Less category' ? 'All category' : 'Less category';
  }).siblings(".complete").toggle();
});
```

```css
.complete {
  display: none;
}
.more {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>kategori 1</li>
  <li>kategori 2</li>
  <li class="complete">kategori 3</li>
  <li class="complete">kategori 4</li>
  <li class="complete">kategori 5</li>
  <li class="more">See all category</li>
</ul>
```